# Self dependency tumbling trigger

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have  defined self-dependency tumbling trigger which will Recurrence every 15 min as shown below.

[image]

Currently we are observing below scenarios:
First pipeline:  first pipeline trigger window from 12/4/2023, 9:37:00 PM - 12/4/2023, 9:52:00 PM (which is 15 min) and pipeline start and end time is from 9:52 to 9:57.
Second pipeline:  pipeline trigger window is from 12/4/2023, 9:52:00 PM - 12/4/2023, 10:07:00 PM ( it is taking first trigger end time which is 9:52 ) and pipeline start and end time is  from 10:07 to 10:11.

We want trigger time should start from end of the pipeline run time e.g.  second pipeline should at start 15 min post completion of first pipeline  . First pipeline is completed at 9:57 next pipeline should start at 10:12 . Could you please suggest on this

not able to achieve method

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you want to have 15 mins gap between two sequent executions. Using 15 mins reoccurrence window may not guarantee always 15 mins gap will be there.

Consider below workaround:

> Whenever pipeline runs, log the end time into some SQL table and then in every next execution fetch the previous end time and calculate 15 mins from it and then use  `wait activity`. In the wait activity set wait time value accordingly. After wait activity completes then only run your pipeline logic